# Uninitialized Constant Error when catching Exception

Tags: ruby, exception

I need to post articles to Wordpress via XMLRPC and catch any exceptions:

```
connection = XMLRPC::Client.new('mysite.com', '/xmlrpc.php', 80)
  connection.call(
  'metaWeblog.newPost',
  1,
  'user',
  'password',
  post,
  true
)
```

There is en error:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:441:in `rescue in pull': #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass> (REXML::ParseException)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:341:in `pull'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/streamparser.rb:16:in `parse'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb:204:in `parse_stream'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/parser.rb:717:in `parse'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/parser.rb:460:in `parseMethodResponse'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:421:in `call2'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:410:in `call'
```

I successfully caught the exception with:

```
connection = XMLRPC::Client.new('mysite.com', '/xmlrpc.php', 80)
begin
  connection.call(
    'metaWeblog.newPost',
    1,
    'user',
    'password',
    post,
    true
  )
rescue REXML::ParseException
  puts "Skipping error"
end
```

Post is OK, article is in Wordpress.

Next I needed to catch an exception about site availability (when site is not accessible)
I tried to catch the exception with:

```
connection = XMLRPC::Client.new('notaccessibleSite.com', '/xmlrpc.php', 80)
begin
  connection.call(
    'metaWeblog.newPost',
    1,
    'user',
    'password',
    post,
    true
  )
rescue REXML::ParseException
  puts "Skipping error"
rescue
  puts "Others errors"
end
```

But this does not work:

```
myscript.rb:47:in `rescue in makeRpc': uninitialized constant Object::REXML (NameError)
from myscript.rb:38:in `makeRpc'
from myscript.rb:62:in `block in postContent'
from myscript.rb:58:in `each'
from myscript.rb:58:in `postContent'
from myscript.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `require 'rexml/document'`. Have a look at the documentation for [rexml/document.rb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/). It requires `'rexml/rexml'` for you as well as `'rexml/parseexception'`.

The following doesn't produce any errors:

```
require "rexml/document"

begin
    doc = REXML::Document.new File.new('blah.txt')
rescue REXML::ParseException => msg
    puts "Failed: #{msg}"
end
```

However if you replace the `rexml/document` with `'rexml/rexml'`, you get:

```
blah.rb:22:in `rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant REXML::ParseException (NameError)
    from abc.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

**Update (based on comments):**

If you want to check that `REXML::ParseException` is defined, something like the following will work:

```
if defined?(REXML::ParseException) == 'constant' && REXML::ParseException.class == Class  
  puts "REXML::ParseException is defined"
else
  puts "REXML::ParseException is NOT defined" 
end
```

Comment: First code produce `No such file or directory - blah.txt (Errno::ENOENT)`. How to catch both exceptions without any errors?

Comment: `require "rexml/document"` works, thank you. But is there way to check existence `REXML::ParseException` ?

Comment: I'll update the answer to show you how to check is `REXML::ParseException` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it can't find Object::REXML when you are testing this case, maybe a `rescue NameError` rescues this.

Comment: I get uninitialized constant either Object::REXML or other (first one in script)

Comment: yes, and the `uninitialized constant` error is a `NameError` which you could use in your rescue statement

Comment: `rescue NameError`
`rescue REXML::ParseException`
and get `uninitialized constant REXML::ParseException (NameError)`

Comment: What i would like: if `REXML::ParseException` exists - make its exception, if not - make exception for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You must `require 'rexml/rexml'` before.

Comment: I have `require 'rexml/rexml'` and `require 'xmlrpc/client'`, no matter.